# Why does not jpa2/eclipselink generate on delete cascade SQL?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

@Entity
public class MUser implements Serializable, MemoEntity {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Meaning> mengs = new HashSet<Meaning>();
```

Shouldn't this mean that I get the constraint with a "on delete cascade"?

This is what gets generated instead:

```
  CREATE TABLE MUSER_MEANING (MUser_EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, mengs_OBJID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (MUser_EMAIL, mengs_OBJID))
CREATE TABLE MUSER_MEANING (MUser_EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, mengs_OBJID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (MUser_EMAIL, mengs_OBJID))
ALTER TABLE MEANING ADD CONSTRAINT MEANING_USR_EMAIL FOREIGN KEY (USR_EMAIL) REFERENCES MUSER (EMAIL)
ALTER TABLE MUSER_MEANING ADD CONSTRAINT MSRMEANINGMsrEMAIL FOREIGN KEY (MUser_EMAIL) REFERENCES MUSER (EMAIL)
```

I'm trying to make it as such that deleting a MUser deletes all Meanings associated to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does not jpa2/eclipselink generate on delete cascade SQL?

Because that's not how things work. Specifying a `cascade=REMOVE` means that the `remove` operation will be cascaded to entities **by the JPA provider**, not at the database level using a constraint.

Some providers do have extensions to use a  cascade delete constraint at the database level instead of the regular mechanism. For example with Hibernate, you can specify:

> `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on joined subclasses: use a SQL cascade delete on deletion instead of the regular Hibernate mechanism.

But I don't know if EclipseLink has something equivalent.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 3.2.3 "Removal"
- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4. Hibernate Annotation Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec)